# Plotly lines using start and end dates

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series, plotly-python

I have a DataFrame with the columns: *start date*, *end date*, and *value*. How can I plot one line for each *start-end date* in Plotly?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
df = pd.DataFrame({"start date": [1,2,3,4], "end date":[8,7,4,9], "value":[11,3,11,4]})
fig = px.line(df, x=["start date","end date"], y="value")
fig.show()
```

In this case, there are only two lines for the columns *start date* and *end date*. However, what I'm looking for is 1 line for each *start-end date*. I tried with the parameter *color="value"* but, in value 11 it only plots 1 line. I could print it with simple plot of *plt* as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [df["start date"], df["end date"]]
y = [df["value"], df["value"]]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: To make sure I got it right: for each line, you’d like x1 and x2 to be the start and end date, respectively, and y1 and y2 to be the values?

Comment: Yes, but in this case, y1 == y2, which means it is a horizontal line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create multiple 'indepent' lines, you'll have to create several traces, like in the example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df = pd.DataFrame({"start date": [1,2,3,4], "end date":[8,7,4,9], "value":[11,3,11,4]})

fig = go.Figure()
for (start, end, value) in zip(df["start date"], df["end date"], df["value"]):
    name = f"{start} to {end}"
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[start, end], y=[value, value],
                    mode='lines', name = name))    


fig.show()
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: So it seems that there is no way to do it with px.line, right? Anyway, your solution is what I am looking for. Thank you. Do you know how to add the information panel in all the line not only in the start-end points?

Comment: Yes, having the hover text in all the line not only in the points.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your plot contains both lines at `y=11`, but they are blue & green and so hard to distinguish. But you can use custom colors, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

colors = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green']
for x1, x2, y, c in zip(df["start date"], df["end date"], df["value"], colors):
    plt.plot([x1, x2], [y, y], color=c)
```

[image]